# How to use NSEnumerator with NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, nsenumerator

How do I use NSEnumerator with NSMutableDictionary, to print out all the keys and values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 94):

Unless you need to use NSEnumerator, you can use fast enumeration (which is faster) and concise.

```
for(NSString *aKey in myDictionary) {
    NSLog(@"%@", aKey);
    NSLog(@"%@", [[myDictionary valueForKey:aKey] string]); //made up method
}
```

Also you can use an Enumerator with fast enumeration:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myDictionary keyEnumerator];

for(NSString *aKey in enumerator) {
    NSLog(@"%@", aKey);
    NSLog(@"%@", [[myDictionary valueForKey:aKey] string]); //made up method
}
```

This is useful for things like doing the reverse enumerator in an array.

Comment: Don't forget you can also enumerate values only from a dictionary if you want:  for (NSString *value in [myDictionary allValues]).

Comment: True, but -allValues does create an intermediate (autoreleased) array, so be aware of the extra storage required.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@)` instead of `NSLog("%@)`.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner You also can use [myDictionary objectEnumerator] to enumerate over all objects, which doesn't create an intermediate array.

Comment: Also, it is perfectly fine to put an enumerator accessor directly inside the for statement,e.g. `for(NSString *aKey in [myDictionary keyEnumerator])`, since the expression after `in` is only evaluated once.

Comment: Thanks for the note about objectEnumerator.  The NSEnumerator I left separate so people would know the type of the thing being returned by that call and could look up docs, in real use I probably would combine that into the for statement as you suggest.

Answer (score 8):

From the [`NSDictionary` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> You can enumerate the contents of a dictionary by key or by value using the `NSEnumerator` object returned by `keyEnumerator` and `objectEnumerator` respectively.

In other words:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myMutableDict keyEnumerator];
id aKey = nil;
while ( (aKey = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil) {
    id value = [myMutableDict objectForKey:anObject];
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", aKey, value);
}
```

Comment: You can also enumerate the keys in the same order with fast enumeration in Objective-C 2.0 — just use for (NSString *key in myMutableDict) { ... } instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the version without object search. Notice that objectForKey calling not exist.
They use keyEnumerator and objectEnumerator both.

```
id aKey = nil;
NSEnumerator *keyEnumerator = [paramaters keyEnumerator];
NSEnumerator *objectEnumerator = [paramaters objectEnumerator];
while ( (aKey = [keyEnumerator nextObject]) != nil) {
    id value = [objectEnumerator nextObject];
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", aKey, value);
}
```

Comment: Is the order guaranteed? I.e., are you sure the value returned by the objectEnumerator is linked to the value returned by the keyEnumerator?