# NSMutableDictionary keyEnumerator or NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` with a structure like:

`Main Dictionary > Unknown Dictionary > Dictionaries 1,2,4,5,6...`

My question is what is the best way to retrieve the Unknown Dictionary key and set it as a variable? This is what I've tried:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myMutableDict keyEnumerator];
id aKey = nil;
while ( (aKey = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil) {
    id value = [myMutableDict objectForKey:aKey]; // changed to `aKey`
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", aKey, value);                // tip via rmaddy
}
```

What goes into `objectForKey:` if you don't know the name of the object in the key?

The other thought I had was to populate an `NSArray`, then pulling each of the keys out somehow.

```
for (NSString *object in myMutableDict)
        myArray = [myArray arrayByAddingObject:MainDict];
}
```

If anyone can suggest a better way to get the object (unknown) from an `NSMutableDictionary` I'm interested to learn.

Comment: Your for loop works fine to let you iterate through all the keys in `myMutableDict`. What's the problem you're asking about?

Comment: @mah, Just wondering the best and most efficient way. Also I'm not sure how the keyEnumerator works exactly. I put a comment in the code I was confused with.

Comment: The call to `objectForKey:` just inside the `while` loop should be `[myMuyableDict objectForKey:aKey]`.

Comment: In all likelihood the efficiency will be close enough for what you're doing, but if you're not sure, you should really run some timing experiments that model _your_ runtime environment as best as you can.

Comment: @rmaddy. Ah, okay. so does it do objects and keys or just keys? I got that code snippet from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1062159/3257552

Comment: @ctfd You are enumerating the keys. You use those keys to get the values.

Comment: @rmaddy, yes the enumeration works very well, thanks for the tip. Why would you use that over a for loop? any particular reason, that's mainly what I'm wondering.

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate dictionaries like this:

```
NSDictionary * someDictionary = ... however you set your dictionary;
[someDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Key: %@", key);
    NSLog(@"Object: %@", obj);


}];
```

and set:

```
*stop = YES;
```

when you find the object you're looking for.

Comment: Are blocks more efficient than the older style syntax, and are there any caveats in using blocks (ARC specific, etc.)? thanks!

Comment: I don't know if they're more efficient.  Caveats - You might have to be a bit more aware of how you're assigning things.  This is mostly relevant for background threads, or when a viewcontroller is referenced in a block that is retained by said viewcontroller.  Using blocks like this really shouldn't cause any problems.  If you want to use local variables, you'll have to put a `__block` specifier.  On a personal note, I absolutely LOVE blocks.  They're immensely useful!

Comment: I personally prefer this solution because it gets me all the objects and keys directly, so it saves me a step or two.

Comment: Hi Logan, thanks for the reply - I've used some __block specifiers actually for some of my filepaths within a dispatch queue, but I've barely scratched the surface with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question correctly. I assume you have a "main" dictionary with exactly one (unknown) key that maps to another dictionary, which you want to retrieve. This would be a simple and concise way to do this:

```
NSDictionary *unknownDictionary = mainDictionary[mainDictionary.allKeys.firstObject];
```

(Yes, some people won't like the dot syntax here, but I find it easier to read in this case. You might also want to add some error checking, for the case that `mainDictionary` is empty etc.)

Comment: thank you for the example. you're correct - i just want to find the best way of getting an unknown value from my dictionary. I've been have some issues with comparing the values with `lastPathComponent` crashing because of unknown selectors. I'm hoping by knowing the keys in advance I can avoid those issues.